# Kernel Density Estimator ( with Gauss Kernel ) Sum f(x) = 1?

Tags: c++, c, gaussian, kernel-density, probability-density

I want to use [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) with the [Gaussian Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29#Kernel_functions_in_common_use). If I'm correct, **the sum of all f(x) must be 1** ( ~ rounding ) ?

My Implementation looks like this:

```
    float K( float const& val)
     {
      const float p=1.0 / std::sqrt( 2.0 * M_PI);
      float result = 0.5 * (val*val);
      result = p * std::exp(- result);

      return result;
     };

std::vector< std::pair<float, float> kde( float *val, int len float h)
{
  std::vector< std::pair<float, float>> density( len );
  const float p = 1.0 / (h * len );

  for(int r=0;r<len;r++)
   {
    float sum = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
     sum += k( (val[r] - val[i]) / h );

    density[r] = std::make_pair( val[r], p*sum );
   }
  return density;
 }
```

And I choosed **h > 0**. Am i right that **p*sum** is the probability for the value **val[r]** ? The sum over all probability is > 1 ( but looks ok for me ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misinterpreted the assumptions on the probability density here. The density *integrates* to one, whereas its values at certain points are definitely not 1.

Let's discuss it using the following formula from [the linked Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) which you seem to use:

[image]

This formula provides the density `f_h(x)` evaluated at point `x`.

From my review, your code correctly evaluates this quantity. Yet, you misinterpreted the quantity which should be one. As a density, the *integral* over the complete space should yield one, i.e.

[image]

This property is called *normalization* of the density.

Moreover, being a density itself, each summand of `f_h(x)` should yield `1/n` when integrated over the whole space, when one also includes the normalization constant. Again, there's no guarantee on the values of the summands.

In one dimension, you can easily confirm the normalization by using the trapezoidal rule or another quadrature scheme (--if you provide a working example, I can try to do that.)

Comment: @Roby: see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec7fedfbd102b5e5). Note that I changed some things, but the integral is always `1` (regardless of the numbers of summands `n`).

Comment: Why divide `(Nx-1)` instead of `Nx` in `double hx=(xN-x0)/(Nx-1);`?

Comment: @user343233: That's the spacing of each interval when you have `Nx` gridpoints. As an example, think of `Nx=2`, there you have only a single interval of length `b-a = (b-a)/1`.